# Is there any tool or somehow to make a OpenStreetMap editor which can manage multi layer in it?

Tags: leaflet, editor, drawing, gis, openstreetmap

I need to build a web application that could draw, edit, import, export,.. map using OSM data. In that, I could add layers and manage like tree form. The layer can be toggled on/off on the map to edit.

```
ex: - building
      + school
      + hospital
      + house
    -way
      +subway
      +highway
```

I tried some editor like iD but it not like what I want.
Does anybody know any tool or any solution to create something like this?

Comment: cross-post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/384283/23837

Comment: Its me and did not have any answer yet. :))) Do u have any idea

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't. If you ask your question at different places then please always add links between them. Otherwise people will waste their time answering a question which has already been answered elsewhere.

Comment: tks for reminding me that